# Access kubernetes service externally

Tags: spring, docker, kubernetes

I'm following the spring and kubernetes integration tutorial:

https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot-kubernetes/

In my current scenario, I have 1 master and 2 workers servers.

When I deploy the file below using the command `kubectl apply -f deployment.yaml`, I can make a request from within the master server using `kubectl port-forward svc/demo 8080:8080` and `curl localhost:8080/actuator/health`.

What I want to do is an external request (a public computer - my computer) to access the service that I created (`kubernetes_master_ip:8080/actuator`), but when I try this, I get "connection refused".

What is missing?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: demo
  name: demo
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: demo
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: demo
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: springguides/demo
        name: demo
        resources: {}
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: demo
  name: demo
spec:
  ports:
  - name: 8080-8080
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: demo
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: See [Publishing Services (ServiceTypes)](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) in the Kubernetes documentation – you need something other than a ClusterIP service (a NodePort service, an Ingress) for it to be reachable externally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the type of service to expose the application. There are two ways:
- LoadBalancer type: (Only on cloud providers)
- NodePort type: Can be done on-premise or minikube.

Change your service yaml to below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: demo
  name: demo
spec:
  ports:
  - name: 8080-8080
    port: 8080
    nodePort: 31234
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: demo
  type: NodePort
```

Once the service is executed. check the application Node IP on which container is created.

```
kubectl get pods -o wide
```

then try to access the application at:
http://node_ip:31234/actuator

Answer (score 1):

you can change your service type to load balancer. Which will expose your service via IP address to the external internet. Service type load balancer will only work with Cloud providers.

For more details you can visit : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: demo
  name: demo
spec:
  ports:
  - name: 8080-8080
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: demo
  type: LoadBalancer
```

save as `yaml` and execute it. it will provide the IP address.

You can access service via IP

```
Kubectl get svc
```